# Mono Compiler not supporting MySQL 5.5

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I am compiling a C# program in Barbary pi 3 (Rasbian 8) consisting of database queries of MySQL 5.5.60.

The C# program gets complied correctly using the compiling command:

```
mcs -r:System.dll -r:System.Data.dll -r:MySql.Data.dll <C#_prog_name>.cs
```

but, after the command: `mono <C#_prog_name>.exe` I am getting the following error:

> Assertion: should not be reached at metadata.c:2860 Stacktrace:     at  <0xffffffff>   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor () [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor (string) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor (string) [0x00019] in
>   :0   at Test.Program.Main ()
>   [0x00015] in <991e93d6783045da929959301015e2dd>:0   at (wrapper
>   runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void
>   (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0004c] in
>   <5a4ea679bdbb464bb25219a3528cae7d>:0 /proc/self/maps:
>   00010000-003bd000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 671        /usr/bin/mono-sgen
>   003cd000-003d1000 r--p 003ad000 b3:02 671        /usr/bin/mono-sgen
>   003d1000-003d4000 rw-p 003b1000 b3:02 671        /usr/bin/mono-sgen
>   003d4000-003e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  019eb000-01b00000 rw-p
>   00000000 00:00 0          [heap] 73f0d000-7420f000 r--p 00000000 b3:02
>   1056151
>   /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   7420f000-744d2000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 1056159
>   /usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   744d2000-74800000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 133099
>   /home/pi/System.Data.dll 74800000-74821000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   74821000-74900000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0  7492c000-7500a000 r-xp
>   00000000 b3:02 1057567    /usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/mscorlib.dll.so
>   7500a000-7501a000 ---p 006de000 b3:02 1057567
>   /usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/mscorlib.dll.so 7501a000-7501b000 rw-p
>   006de000 b3:02 1057567    /usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/mscorlib.dll.so
>   7501b000-7502e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  7502e000-75400000 r--p
>   00000000 b3:02 1055997    /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll
>   75400000-75c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  75c00000-75c01000 ---p
>   00000000 00:00 0  75c01000-76400000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
>   76400000-76800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  76954000-7695d000 r--p
>   00000000 b3:02 1059470
>   /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Transactions/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
>   7695d000-769b8000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 132761
>   /home/pi/MySql.Data.dll 769b8000-769b9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   769b9000-76ab8000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0  76ab8000-76b38000 rw-p
>   00000000 00:00 0  76b39000-76b49000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
>   76b49000-76b4a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  76b4a000-76b79000 ---p
>   00000000 00:00 0  76b79000-76d02000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 346
>   /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive 76d02000-76e2d000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02
>   137259     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.19.so 76e2d000-76e3d000
>   ---p 0012b000 b3:02 137259     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.19.so 76e3d000-76e3f000 r--p 0012b000 b3:02 137259
>   /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.19.so 76e3f000-76e40000 rw-p 0012d000
>   b3:02 137259     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.19.so
>   76e40000-76e43000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  76e43000-76e60000 r-xp
>   00000000 b3:02 138741     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1
>   76e60000-76e6f000 ---p 0001d000 b3:02 138741
>   /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 76e6f000-76e70000 rw-p 0001c000
>   b3:02 138741     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1
>   76e70000-76e84000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 137291
>   /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.19.so 76e84000-76e94000 ---p
>   00014000 b3:02 137291     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.19.so
>   76e94000-76e95000 r--p 00014000 b3:02 137291
>   /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.19.so 76e95000-76e96000 rw-p
>   00015000 b3:02 137291     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.19.so
>   76e96000-76e98000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  76e98000-76e9a000 r-xp
>   00000000 b3:02 137275     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.19.so
>   76e9a000-76ea9000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 137275
>   /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.19.so 76ea9000-76eaa000 r--p 00001000
>   b3:02 137275     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.19.so
>   76eaa000-76eab000 rw-p 00002000 b3:02 137275
>   /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.19.so 76eab000-76eb1000 r-xp 00000000
>   b3:02 137287     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.19.so
>   76eb1000-76ec0000 ---p 00006000 b3:02 137287
>   /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.19.so 76ec0000-76ec1000 r--p 00005000
>   b3:02 137287     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.19.so
>   76ec1000-76ec2000 rw-p 00006000 b3:02 137287
>   /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.19.so 76ec2000-76f2b000 r-xp 00000000
>   b3:02 137276     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.19.so
>   76f2b000-76f3b000 ---p 00069000 b3:02 137276
>   /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.19.so 76f3b000-76f3c000 r--p 00069000
>   b3:02 137276     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.19.so
>   76f3c000-76f3d000 rw-p 0006a000 b3:02 137276
>   /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.19.so 76f3d000-76f42000 rw-p 00000000
>   00:00 0  76f42000-76f44000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 132298
>   /home/pi/decrypt_file_cs_to_cpp_code.exe 76f44000-76f54000 rwxp
>   00000000 00:00 0  76f54000-76f59000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 18033
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so 76f59000-76f68000 ---p
>   00005000 b3:02 18033      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so
>   76f68000-76f69000 rw-p 00004000 b3:02 18033
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so 76f69000-76f89000 r-xp
>   00000000 b3:02 137256     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.19.so
>   76f89000-76f8a000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 56217
>   /usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo 76f8a000-76f90000 rw-p
>   00000000 00:00 0  76f90000-76f91000 rw-s 00000000 00:10 44948
>   /dev/shm/mono.20562 76f91000-76f92000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   76f92000-76f93000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0  76f93000-76f98000 rw-p
>   00000000 00:00 0  76f98000-76f99000 r--p 0001f000 b3:02 137256
>   /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.19.so 76f99000-76f9a000 rw-p 00020000
>   b3:02 137256     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.19.so 7ed97000-7edb8000
>   rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [stack] 7ef7b000-7ef7c000 r-xp 00000000
>   00:00 0          [sigpage] 7ef7c000-7ef7d000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0
>   [vvar] 7ef7d000-7ef7e000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
>   ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]  Native
>   stacktrace:   Debug info from gdb:  Cannot access memory at address
>   0x0 Mono support loaded. [New LWP 20564] [New LWP 20563] [Thread
>   debugging using libthread_db enabled] Using host libthread_db library
>   "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1". 0x76e7fef8 in
>   __libc_waitpid (Cannot access memory at address 0x0 pid=20565, stat_loc=0x7edb5b38, options=0) at
>   ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:40 40
>   ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c: No such file or directory.   Id 
>   Target Id         Frame    3    Thread 0x763ff450 (LWP 20563) "SGen
>   worker" 0x76e7b7a4 in __pthread_cond_wait (Cannot access memory at
>   address 0x50 cond=0x3ded58, mutex=0x3ded1c) at pthread_cond_wait.c:187
>   2    Thread 0x76ab7450 (LWP 20564) "Finalizer" 0x76e7da40 in
>   do_futex_wait (isem=isem@entry=0x3d6f98) at
>   ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_wait.c:48 * 1    Thread 0x76f93000
>   (LWP 20562) "mono" 0x76e7fef8 in __libc_waitpid (Cannot access memory
>   at address 0x0 pid=20565, stat_loc=0x7edb5b38, options=0) at
>   ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:40  Thread 3 (Thread 0x763ff450
>   (LWP 20563)): Cannot access memory at address 0x50 #0  0x76e7b7a4 in
>   __pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x3ded58, mutex=0x3ded1c) at pthread_cond_wait.c:187 #1  0x002dd054 in ?? () Cannot access memory
>   at address 0x50 Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this
>   frame (corrupt stack?)  Thread 2 (Thread 0x76ab7450 (LWP 20564)): #0 
>   0x76e7da40 in do_futex_wait (isem=isem@entry=0x3d6f98) at
>   ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_wait.c:48 #1  0x76e7daf4 in
>   __new_sem_wait (sem=0x3d6f98) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_wait.c:69 #2  0x0026cb50 in ?? ()
>   Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt
>   stack?)  Thread 1 (Thread 0x76f93000 (LWP 20562)): Cannot access
>   memory at address 0x0 #0  0x76e7fef8 in __libc_waitpid (pid=20565,
>   stat_loc=0x7edb5b38, options=0) at
>   ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:40 #1  0x000d2a50 in ?? () Cannot
>   access memory at address 0x0 Backtrace stopped: previous frame
>   identical to this frame (corrupt stack?) 
>   ================================================================= Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
>   error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your
>   application.
>   =================================================================  Aborted
>
> ---

Comment: what version of Mono are you using?

Comment: we used mono debian 9 version, got compilation error related MySQL later we used maria DB simillar to MySQL then the issue got Fixed.